# Какое наклонение глагола во фразе "ты бы спал"?

Tags: глаголы, морфология

> Ты бы не *читал*, а *спал*.

Какое наклонение у глаголов в этом предложении? С одной стороны есть свойства **условного** наклонения, потому что есть частица *бы*. С другой стороны, чувствуется **повелительное** наклонение, потому что предлагается что-то делать (спать).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы правы, здесь форма условного наклонения используется в значении повелительного - морфологическое средство выразительности. Так и в разборе пишут: "условное в знач. повелит."

Answer (score 3):

Многое здесь зависит от контекста. Возможен такой, в котором эта фраза утрачивает оттенок повелительности. Достаточно поместить перед ней такую фразу:
"Вот прописал бы тебе доктор снотворное с утра."

Или такую - с переориентацией частицы "бы" на подлежащее:
"Тебе бы мои завтрашние хлопоты. Ты бы [на моём месте] не читал, а спал."